# Error while executing a query in Databricks sql editor

Tags: azure, databricks

While executing a simple query in Databricks sql editor warehouse, i'm getting below issue:

Failure to initialize configuration for storage account

`devadls.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key`

Comment: I understood that, storage account key's need to pass, but in sql editor how can i pass it? if it is notebook we can try spark.conf.

Comment: Could you please provide your sample code?

Comment: have you tried the methods 
https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html? 
Btw, it is highly risky practice to use account keys in a notebook. It is better to use Identities, SAS  (account keys only if necessary). The article describes sufficiently how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the procedure below to read or access files from Azure Data Lake Gen2 using Databricks SQL.

Mount the storage account using the code below in a Databricks Python notebook:

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)
```

Create a table by reading a file from ADLS Gen2 using Databricks with the code below:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE sample
  USING <fileFormat>
  OPTIONS (
    'header' 'true',  
    'inferSchema' 'true',
    'path' '/mnt/<mountPoint>/<filePath>'
  )
```

Then, you can query the tables in SQL successfully as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM <tableName>
```

[image]

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEST1 USING CSV OPTIONS (path "/mnt/abc.csv", header "true")
Yes the above query is working.